# How to use exclude_properties and include_properties to exclude/include SQLAlchemy model attributes from corresponding Spyne model?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, spyne

I have model declared as:

```
class SAProduct(Base):

    sku = Column(PRODUCT_SKU_TYPE, primary_key=True)
    i_want_to_hide = Column(String(20), nullable=False)
    name = Column(Unicode(255), nullable=True)

    @property
    def my_property(self):
        return i_calculate_property_here(self)
```

and Spyne model declared as:

```
db = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:')
Session = sessionmaker(bind=db)

class TableModel(ComplexModelBase):
    __metaclass__ = ComplexModelMeta
    __metadata__ = MetaData(bind=db)

class SProduct(TableModel):
    __table__ = SAProduct.__table__
```

How can I make attribute `i_want_to_hide` to be excluded from Spyne model, and property `my_property` to be included as Spyne model attribute?

P.S.
Now I use monkey patching Spyne to support this syntax:

```
class SProduct(GComplexModel):
    __model__ = Product

    class Attributes:
        exclude_attrs = ('i_want_to_hide',)
        add_attrs = {'my_property': Boolean}
```

But I want get rid of it.

Comment: What is `__model__` ? What is `GComplexModel` ?

Comment: It appears that we have built some metadata on top of original Spyne-SQLAlchemy integration. I will update my question and let you know. Thank you for support.

Comment: @BurakArslan I have fixed my question. Should I use Attributes.sqla_mapper_args to include/exclude properties. Could you give me a snippet that demonstrates this?

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't directly answer your question, but please consider the following code:

```
from spyne import *

TableModel = TTableModel()

class SomeClass(TableModel):
    __tablename__ = 'some_table'

    id = Integer(pk=True)
    s = Unicode
    i = Integer(exc_table=True)
```

Here, `pk` stands for primary key (you can use the long form `primary_key` if you wish) and the `i` attribute will just be ignored by SqlAlchemy. e.g. it won't be created in the table, it won't be instrumented by SqlAlchemy's metaclass, etc.

As for an attribute that will be hidden from the RPC Parts of Spyne, but not from SqlAlchemy, that's a new feature coming in 2.12.

You will be able to say e.g.:

```
i = Integer(exc_table=True, pa={JsonObject: dict(exc=true)})
```

where `pa` stands for protocol attributes. (you can use the long form `prot_attrs` if you wish) Here `i` is ignored by every protocol that inherits JsonObject.

If you don't want it on the wsdl either, you'll have to do:

```
i = Integer(exc_table=True, exc_interface=True)
```

https://github.com/arskom/spyne/blob/fa4b1eef5815d3584287d1fef66b61846f82d2f8/spyne/interface/xml_schema/model.py#L197

Spyne offers a richer object model interface compared to SqlAlchemy. Trying to replicate this functionality without adding Spyne as a dependency means you'll have to duplicate all the work done in Spyne in your project. It's your choice!

Comment: There is a inconvenience with this solution, because it requires to redefine fields on Spyne model, just to exclude them, although field is already defined on SQLAlchemy model. I would prefer to list fields that should be excluded from Spyne visibility.

Comment: Once you define the Spyne model, you're supposed to do away with the SQLAlchemy ones -- Spyne models are drop-in replacements.